# Itunes connect demo account for reviewing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, sandbox

Do I must to add to "Sandbox" a demo account for Apple reviewing?
(for testing IAP purchases)

Thanks.

Comment: You only need to provide a demo account if an account is required to log in to your app, or use its features. Apple reviewers have their own accounts for testing in app purchases.

Comment: Yes, you need to give "Sandbox" account credentials to Apple review team in case of IAP.